On the power of QMA(2)
I searched for references. But I could not find any. Is $EXP\subseteq QMA(2)$ known?

The inclusion $EXP\subseteq QMA(2)$ is not known, and in fact is not expected to hold. It would imply that any exponential-size computation could be verified in polynomial time. In fact, the inclusion $QMA(2)\subseteq EXP$ is also unknown, according to Aaronson et al. [1].
The best known inclusions are
$$QMA\subseteq QMA(2)\subseteq NEXP $$
[1] S. Aaronson, S. Beigi, A. Drucker, B. Fefferman and P. Shor. The power of unentanglement. Theory of Computing, 5(1):1-42, 2009. arXiv:0804.0802
